How to modify headers and response uisng selenium wire
I am trying to loginto this website
https://home.cccapply.org/en/apply
but getting response
https://www.opencccapply.net/cccapply-welcome?cccMisCode=344
A proxy connection has been detected. To connect to California Community Colleges you must disable anonymizing services. This may include:
Tor web browser
VPN connections
Anonymizing browser plugins
I tried to use selenium wire but was unable use it
